# Strange mysql query execution time behavior

Tags: sql, mysql

hello
i'm having a strange execution time behavior over almost same sql queries

q1:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`key`, `t1`.`module`, `t2`.`value` 
FROM `translates` AS `t1` 
LEFT JOIN `translates_i18n` AS `t2` ON (`t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id` AND `t2`.`culture` = 'en') 
WHERE `t1`.`module` IN ('GLOBAL','AJAX','FORMS', .... about 15 items) LIMIT 9000;
```

0.10 sec

q2:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`key`, `t2`.`value` 
FROM `translates` AS `t1` 
LEFT JOIN `translates_i18n` AS `t2` ON (`t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id` AND `t2`.`culture` = 'en') 
WHERE `t1`.`module` IN ('GLOBAL','AJAX','FORMS', .... about 15 items) LIMIT 9000;
```

0.000... sec

tables definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `translates` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `module` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `system` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `key` (`key`,`module`),
  KEY `module` (`module`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `translates_i18n` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `culture` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`culture`),
  KEY `culture` (`culture`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `translates_i18n`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `translates_i18n_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `translates` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

difference between q1 & q2 is in `t1`.`module` column, that is also in where statement

i just cant see where is the problem, please, anyone poit me

**update**

q1:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  `t1`.`id` ,  `t1`.`key` ,  `t1`.`module` ,  `t2`.`value` 
    -> FROM  `translates` AS  `t1` 
    -> LEFT JOIN  `translates_i18n` AS  `t2` ON (  `t2`.`id` =  `t1`.`id` 
    -> AND  `t2`.`culture` =  'en' ) 
    -> WHERE  `t1`.`module` 
    -> IN (
    -> 'GLOBAL',  'AJAX',  'FORMS',  'ROOTMENU',  'LANGSWITCHER',  'AUTHORIZATION',  'MENU',  'MINIFY',  'SIMPLESHOP'
    -> )
    -> LIMIT 100500
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | index  | module          | key     | 1534    | NULL                |  627 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,culture | PRIMARY | 12      | theloom.t1.id,const |    1 |                          |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

q2:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  `t1`.`id` ,  `t1`.`key` ,  `t2`.`value` 
    -> FROM  `translates` AS  `t1` 
    -> LEFT JOIN  `translates_i18n` AS  `t2` ON (  `t2`.`id` =  `t1`.`id` 
    -> AND  `t2`.`culture` =  'en' ) 
    -> WHERE  `t1`.`module` 
            -> IN (
    -> 'GLOBAL',  'AJAX',  'FORMS',  'ROOTMENU',  'LANGSWITCHER',  'AUTHORIZATION',  'MENU',  'MINIFY',  'SIMPLESHOP'
    -> )
    -> LIMIT 100500;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | index  | module          | key     | 1534    | NULL                |  627 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,culture | PRIMARY | 12      | theloom.t1.id,const |    1 |                          |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Show `EXPLAIN` for both queries.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at that, I think the reason is like due to [the INNODB Buffer Pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html).  The first query starts with a clean buffer, so before it can process the query, it needs to read the index into memory.  Then when you run the second query, it's already in memory, so it runs much faster.

Try adding a `FLUSH TALBES` command between each query.

You can also try using the [`Benchmark()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark) function to test this.

The other thing that could be causing the difference is the size of the data to be transfered.  I see the additional column is declared `VARCHAR(255)`.  Is it perhaps that the column has a lot of data, and 9000 rows really does increase the network overhead that significantly...

Some things to investigate at least...

Comment: the tables are in innodb, not myisam, so the key cache is not an issue
i dont see any reason to flush tables, this queries are independent, i need the 1st query form my system, but for some reason its slow, so i've investigated why it is slow and found out that it is slow when i select a column that is in WHERE

Comment: +1 most likely just time to fill some memory with 9000 varchar(255) values. The plans are exactly the same so it has to be data-volume related

Comment: @VoSi: good spot, edited from KeyCache to Buffer Pool...  Something to try: Run the queries each a few hundred times, and average the times.  Then it will tell you if it's a buffer pool issue or not.  Also check with something like wireshark to see how much data is actually transmitted (which will tell you if the difference is on the network stack)...

Comment: and there is not 9000 entries, its barely get to 700, and i need them all

Comment: If there are not 9000, why is your limit 9000?  Is it a magic number? If you need all results, don't even add a Limit...

Comment: well, in working system there is no limit, i have added it here for presentation purposes )

Comment: i've ran over 9000 time )
and its all the same - 0.10 sec with module field ... and 0.00000... without

Comment: With `SQL_NO_CACHE` as you have in your `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: with it and without it - all the same: 0.0000.. without `module` and 0.10 with it

Comment: @cyberkiwi the tables are less than 1mbyte in size. And query result contains max 500 rows in some cases (max 100kbytes). I've found another hint, when i'm using limit 30 - execution time is normal ... its all very strange, maybe i should upgrade mysql? ))) the problem is very odd

Comment: Wouldn't you still expect retrieving an extra column to take a little more time?

Comment: its not "a little more", its on several orders more, it just could be so

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion against the other answer, and the addition of no-cache, it is unlikely to have anything to do with any caching.  The plans are exactly the same as well, so there's nothing in that direction.

The most likely causes is therefore to do with the retrieval and storage of varchar(255) columns.

Try these 3 new queries and see what you get:

Count the length only, still processes the module column somewhat

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`key`, Length(`t1`.`module`), `t2`.`value` 
FROM `translates` AS `t1` 
LEFT JOIN `translates_i18n` AS `t2` ON (`t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id` AND `t2`.`culture` = 'en') 
WHERE `t1`.`module` IN ('GLOBAL','AJAX','FORMS', .... about 15 items) LIMIT 9000;
```

Test only the mask whether it is null

```
SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`key`, case when `t1`.`module` is null then 1 else 0 end, `t2`.`value` 
FROM `translates` AS `t1` 
LEFT JOIN `translates_i18n` AS `t2` ON (`t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id` AND `t2`.`culture` = 'en') 
WHERE `t1`.`module` IN ('GLOBAL','AJAX','FORMS', .... about 15 items) LIMIT 9000;
```

Gathers the total length of varchars involved

```
SELECT Length(GROUP_CONCAT(module))
FROM
(
    SELECT `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`key`, `t1`.`module`, `t2`.`value` 
    FROM `translates` AS `t1` 
    LEFT JOIN `translates_i18n` AS `t2` ON (`t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id` AND `t2`.`culture` = 'en') 
    WHERE `t1`.`module` IN ('GLOBAL','AJAX','FORMS', .... about 15 items) LIMIT 9000
) X
```

Comment: q1: time 0.0004ms min length is 4 max is 13

Comment: q2: everything is 0, no null module field

Comment: I think it is reinforcing the fact that the more you do with module, the longer it takes.  I forgot that length count is pretty efficient since it only looks at the leading bytes of the varchar, so it would pale in insignificance to actually retrieving the data, but 0.0004ms is already a change.

Comment: mysql> select `module` from translates group by module;



AJAX AUTHORIZATION FORMS GLOBAL MAILLIST MEDIA MENU SIMPLESHOP STATICTEXT WYSIWYG

Comment: group by module only gives distincts, each one appears many times in the full result. any times for q2, q3?

Comment: q2: first 0.002 second 0.0004

Comment: q3: first 0.032 second 0.0063, result 1024

Comment: _Take with a load of scepticism (results from single run not averaged). _ So to check the null bitmap on the record - 0.4ns.  To check the length (2 bytes on the varchar record itself) - 2ns (factor of 5).  And to actually collect the module varchar data, merge them and take the length, 32ns (another factor of 16).  It seems reasonable that to preserve all 700 rows of varchar values in the final result output, 0.1 (only 3 times more than 0.032) is reasonable.

Comment: The first vs second timings are useful, they show the effect of buffering.

Comment: so why there is no difference betwn first run and second run in my q1?

Comment: You have not shown second run for q1, but the numbers at .4ms is too small to be significant.  Other factors come into play that affect it more than the query itself